# F6 key not working in NetBeans 7.4

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-7.4

I am using NetBeans IDE 7.4 to code my programs. The problem of it is that, the F6 key is not working. That means the program is not running when F6 is pressed. Nothing is happening when F6 is pressed.

I use a Lenovo G500 laptop. My OS is Windows 8. Now I use HP G62 notebook. Its OS is Windows 7. It too has the same problem.

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Did you define a main project? And does that main project have a default main class?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes. The same things can be run on other machines by pressing F6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many newer laptops have reprogrammed the Function keys up top to be something different than F1-F12. So to make the F6 key work in NetBeans, use the 'fn' ket with it. That is 'fn+F6'. It will work for you.